# Android Json error parsing data

Tags: android, json

I get an error while parsing the json. I've been on some post but apparently this problem is caused by several causes. Thank you for giving me a bit of your time.
My goal is to send the content type into a editText to a php file that decais to return type information content entered is incorrect or not

This my Login Class

```
package com.example.androidapp3;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.androidapp3.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.androidapp3.library.UserFunctions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Login extends Activity {

    Button btnLogin;
    EditText inputCodePin;

    private TextView loginErrorMsg;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String KEY_NOM = "nom";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_CODEPIN = "codepin";
    private static final String KEY_ROLE = "role";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
        inputCodePin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codepin);

/**
 * Login button click event
 **/
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputCodePin.getText().toString())) {
                        NetAsync(view);
                } else {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Veuillez entrer un code pin valide svp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
 **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Verification réseau");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
        **/
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Verifiez votre connexion");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
     **/
    private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String codepin;// = inputCodePin.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            inputCodePin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codepin);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Vérification de données");
            pDialog.setMessage("Patientez ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(codepin);
            return json;
        }
            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
               if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NOM),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_CODEPIN),json_user.getString(KEY_PHONE),json_user.getString(KEY_ROLE),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                       /**
                        *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                        **/
                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /**
                         * Close Login Screen
                         **/
                        finish();
                    }else{

                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Code Pin Incorrect");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    }
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

//JSONParser

```
package com.example.androidapp3.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

//Log

```
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/JSON Parser(8900): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
09-30 07:17:34.010: W/dalvikvm(8900): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a799d8)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at com.example.androidapp3.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:168)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at com.example.androidapp3.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4471)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
09-30 07:17:34.010: E/AndroidRuntime(8900):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show what is your line no: `Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:168)` ?

Comment: Check response.. probably you are getting a blank response from server.

Comment: What's line Login.java:168?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: @GrlsHu @MysticMagic this my line no:168 `try {
               if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {`

Comment: Mostly your `json` is null. Please debug

Comment: @MysticMagic I manage always not to understand why my json is null.
I allocated the value read from the editext to the codepin variable
`String codepin = inputCodePin.getText().toString();` but it is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ProcessLogin` method's `onPostExecute()` check for the null value of your `JsonObject`.

```
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       if(json != null)
       {
          try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
             ................................
```

Comment: Thank a lot! The problem is solved but the crash however the application can more stops more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank a lot @GrlsHu! The problem of the crash is solved. However, the application does not stop any more. More than **10 minutes** which I launched requests and since I have the **message of ProgressDialog** which turns